# How to get the output from the OSC receiving function with pyOSC

Tags: python, function, output, osc

I have a very basic question, I suppose. I am using pyOSC library to receive OSC messages with Python.

The code I use is this:

```
import OSC 
import time, threading 
receive_address = '127.0.0.1', 9000 

def printing_handler(addr, tags, stuff, source): 
    print "---" 
    print "received new osc msg from %s" % OSC.getUrlStr(source) 
    print "with addr : %s" % addr 
    print "typetags %s" % tags 
    print "data %s" % stuff 
    print "---" 

s = OSC.OSCServer(receive_address)
s.addMsgHandler("/valueToNetwork", printing_handler) 
st = threading.Thread( target = s.serve_forever ) 
st.start()
```

I then want to use the values in stuff as variables OUTSIDE the function, so I put `return stuff;` as last line but got a message when doing `print printing_handler`.

The message I get is: `<function printing_handler at 0x76a78e70>` in the sh window.

Comment: "but got an error when doing" - what error did you get?

Comment: Hi thanks for answering something and sorry for delay in answering back. I actually get: <function printing_handler at 0x76a78e70>
in the sh window. So that is not an error, I think